# Definition of principal homogeneous space for elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Definition of principal homogeneous space for elliptic curves, for example, in $p322$ of 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves'.

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve defined over a field $K$.

**Principal homogeneous space** for $E/K$ is defined as a '**curve**'$C$ which $E/K$ acts simply transitively as algebraic group.

In this definition, is $C$ only projective curve ?
What is wrong with if we admit $C$ to be affine curve ?

Comment: If $C$ is affine, all morphisms from $E$ to $C$ (even after changing base to an algebraically closed field) are constant – so $C$ can’t be a torsor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ \alpha : E\times C \longrightarrow C $$
be the assumed simple transitive action. Consider the map on points over an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$, i.e.,
$$ \alpha : E(\overline{K})\times C(\overline{K}) \longrightarrow C(\overline{K}). $$
Fix a base point $Q_0\in C(\overline{K})$. Then given a point $Q\in C(\overline{K})$, the simple transitivity of the action says that there is a unique point $\beta(Q)\in E(\overline{K})$ that satisfies
$$ \alpha\bigl(\beta(Q),Q_0\bigr)=Q. $$
The map $\beta:C\to E$ is an isomorphism, it's inverse is the map
$$  E\longrightarrow C,\quad P \longmapsto \alpha(P,Q_0). $$
So the fact that $E$ is a smooth projective curve implies that $C$ is also a smooth projective currve.